# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted] web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

When calling from Remix IDE, it executes successfully.
But when calling from web3 v1.2.9, it gives the above error.

Here is the contract :
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8ec0ca8b2fb402ff86cee42ade5e9072a6156b63#code

sol code:

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at Etherscan.io on 2020-07-16
*/

pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract SendEther {
    
    event Transferred(uint256 value , address sender);
    
    function() external payable{}
    
    function SendEtherToAddresses(address payable[] memory _addresses, uint256[] memory _amounts) public payable {
        
        for (uint256 i=0; i < _amounts.length; i++) {
            _addresses[i].transfer(_amounts[i]);
        }
        
    emit Transferred(msg.value, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

js code:

```
window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
ethereum.enable();
eth_Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

var addresses = '0xB0Dc12Ef30D707A52a079d915435Ee0B5C03e8CC';
var amounts = '0.0005'

const address = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(ethAddress); // metamask address

  Eth_Add_Arr = addresses.split(",");
  Eth_Amt_Arr = amounts.split(",");

                        var Eth_Amt_Arr_1=new Array();
                        TotalAmount = 0;

                        for (var i = 0; i < Eth_Amt_Arr.length; i++) {

                            var x = parseInt(web3.utils.toWei(Eth_Amt_Arr[i], "ether"));
                            Eth_Amt_Arr_1[i] = x.toString();
                            TotalAmount += x;
                        };

                        eth_Contract.methods.SendEtherToAddresses(Eth_Add_Arr, Eth_Amt_Arr_1).send({
                            from: address,
                            to: contractAddress,
                            value: TotalAmount,
                            gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("1", "Gwei"),
                            gas: 40000
                        },
                            (error, transactionHash) => {
                                if (!error) {
                                    console.log(transactionHash);
                                    SaveRegistration(address, sponsorId, transactionHash);
                                }
                                else {
                                    swal(e);
                                }
                        })
```

Please help!

Comment: Your question:
Good afternoon, I'm your follower and would like some help
Transfer ethereum from metamask to Uniswap
From Uniswap I bought the pool currency, but today I received the following message: Fail with error 'Transaction too old'
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted] How do I retrieve the ethereum value I sent
You sent today at 11:21
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check last transaction:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd45d32f88b6f8fc88c1a5984bf9d85aea50d6e50df0c22f461e39557d1296b6c

```
#   Name        Type        Data
0   _addresses  address[]   b3f17500e86c3cce3ecb47aba1073c4ffa940ec5
1   _amounts    uint256[]   500000000000000
```

You try send *ETH* to another contract `0xb3f17500E86c3Cce3Ecb47ABa1073c4FFA940eC5`which cannot accept *ETH* because it has no fallback function like sender contract:

```
function() external payable{}
```